# Request.InputStream empty

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

A number of years ago I wrote a .aspx page that handled a HTTP POST Request which contained a piece of xml.  The code read the xml using Request.InputStream - it worked fine for years until The DNN site that it was running in was updated to 5.6.8 now Request.InputStream is always empty.  Note that the page is completely separate to DNN but located in site.com/Special/tlweb.aspx .

I've tested the same page on the same server using .net 4 but with a different IIS site and it works fine.  Since another app POSTS data to the current URL I need to get it working in the existing location - changing the app is not an option.

I kind of think something was done in DNN 5.6.8 that was intended to stop cross site scripting attacks but I'm really having trouble figuring out what changed and what I can do to ensure that the specific page runs as it did previously.

Can anyone make any suggestions please?

Thanks
Josh

Comment: Are you posting from client-side javascript or from code behind?

Comment: It turned out that some DNN module called iFinity Url Master Version : 2.7 - I disabled it and the problem was resolved.